# Not able to get date in string format

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm storing some dates in coredata in `Date` format. In another viewcontroller, I want to retrieve those dates and convert them to string. I tried to achieve it like so...

```
if let bday = result.birthday {

print(bday)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let bDateString = formatter.string(from: bday as Date)
print(bDateString)
self.birthdate = bDateString

}
```

Here, printing `bday` gives the proper date. But printing `bDateString` after converting to string gives nil. What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: Need to assign date formate to formatter object like formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy" in which you want o/p.

Comment: may be you forget to set date fromate like formtter.dateformate = "your date formate"

Comment: can you print this`bday`

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns. You can also check all the available formats in DateFormatter which you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide format of date like this :

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy" //provide your date format here
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have not provided date format.

Even you can use this extension

```
extension Date {    static func getFormattedDate(string: String) -> String{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz" // This formate is input formated .

        let formateDate = dateFormatter.date(from:"2018-02-02 06:50:16 +0000")!
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // Output Formated

        print ("Print :\(dateFormatter.string(from: formateDate))")//Print :02-02-2018
        return dateFormatter.string(from: formateDate)
    } }
```